# Help me to understand the time component of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, mass, mass-energy

Mass = Force / acceleration  (in this one the speed is changing through acceleration)
and
Mass = Energy / $c^2$   (in this one the speed is constant)

In both of these, there is a time component that I can't grasp.  Beyond just reworking the formulas, how or why does mass change with time in both of these?

Comment: You are, very badly, confusing [Newtonian mechanics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) with [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass–energy_equivalence). Also, see [variable mass systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system) in context of classical mechanics.

Comment: @FakeMod  Sorry, I was not confusing them, but rather using them as two completey separate and distinct instances where mass and time are related.

Comment: Oh, I see. But even then, the context of both the equations is very different. Anyways, going through the links in my previous comment will definitely help you clear this.

Comment: Maybe a little rephrasing would help. Right now I can't understand precisely what you are asking. Try to be more specific if you can.

Comment: @Noumeno  I mention in a comment lower down the relationship between mass and inertia.   Inertia implies movement which implies time.  Then I looked at the formulas in the OP, so now I'm trying to understand how time and mass are related.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is generally a bad idea to divide vectors. Write the equation as $m \vec{a} = \vec{F}$ or $\vec{a} = \vec{F} / m$.
The mass is a scalar number (it has no time component) and describes the amount of matter or inertia. It does not change in the dynamics.

Comment: You say that "... describes the amount of matter or inertia".    This is where my question arose late last night.  "Inertia" implies movement which implies time.  And that led to my looking at the formulas in the OP.  There is a time component, I'm just looking to get a better grasp on it.

Comment: @foolishmuse inertia is resistance to change in  motion and this resistance is just some property of the object. It is like saying something is blue. Blue has no time component, it is just property of the object. Even though you could create similar argument to yours of the type "blue implies wavelength, which implies frequency, which implies time" One must be careful with implications "The more I drink, the more I am drunk. The more I am drunk, the more my hands shake. The more my hands shake, the more I spill. The more I spill, the less I drink. Therefore the more I drink, the less I drink."

Comment: I've found this video on relativistic mass https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTJauaefTZM that helps me to understand what I was thinking of. Thanks to all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The $c^2$ term is the conversion constant for going back and forth between mass and energy units. It has nothing at all to do with Newton's $\vec F = m \vec a$ law.

In $m = F/a$ as written, the mass term is *not changing* that is, varying the *acceleration* does *not* magically cause the *mass* to change.

Answer (score 0):

Inertial mass in classical mechanics can be measured by the relation between force and acceleration. So it is necessary some time to make the measurement, but it doesn't mean it is a function of time.

For the relativistic equation, $E = m$ for the frame where the mass is at rest. Velocity of light is only a constant.